# Access server props from within redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-engine

I'm trying to use `redux`, `react-engine`, and `react-router`.

The issue or question I have is that `react-engine` provides an object of `props` that come from the server. How do I access these props from within my `ProvidedApp`?

**ProvidedApp.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './app'
import { mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, store } from './redux-stuff'

// Connected Component
let ConnectedApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

let ProvidedApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp/>
  </Provider>
)

export default ProvidedApp
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'

import Layout from './views/Layout'
import App from './views/ProvidedApp'

module.exports = (
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <Route path='/app' component={App} />
      <Route path='/app/dev' component={App} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

I also think my configuration is a little wonky, I couldn't get `Provider` working any other way. If theres a way to have `Provider` wrap the `Router` I'd love to get that working.

---

Here's some code of what it looks like when I move `Provider` above `Router`

**ConnectedApp.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './app'
import { mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps} from './redux-stuff'

let ConnectedApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

export default ConnectedApp
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import { store } from './redux-stuff'

import Layout from './views/Layout'
import App from './views/ConnectedApp'

module.exports = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
        <Route path='/app' component={App} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)
```

I get this error:

`Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".`

---

*Update*

I found that I can access from he code in my first example within `ProvidedApp`. But I have no clue how I'm supposed to pass it into Redux.

```
let ProvidedApp = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedApp/>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you do `<Provider store={store}><Router> ... </Router></Provider>` ?

Comment: @VonD This error: `Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".`

Comment: @VonD Updated what my code looks like :(

Comment: OK. What versions of React and react-redux are you using ? Are you sure there is only one version of React being used ? https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props

Comment: Have you instantiated the Redux store on the server? I could be mistaken, but this looks like client-side code, that is, none seem to import `renderToString` from `react-dom/server`, which is utilized server-side. Not sure if you've encountered: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: @lux, I'm using [react-engine](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine) to do the server side rendering. That `Routes.js` file is used by both the server and client.

Comment: @VonD `"react": "^0.14.7", "redux": "^3.3.1",` can't see how I'd be using more than one version of react, I'm using webpack.

Comment: @ThomasReggi this can very well happen, even with webpack, and that can cause some context props to be missing. check out this article : https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#.hmc9rdspd with some explanations and nice troubleshooting tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I need to wrap the `reducer` and `store` and pass in the `ServerProps` to the default state like this.

```
let getDefaultState = (serverProps) => {
  return {
    'appName': serverProps.appName 
  }
}

let getReducer = (serverProps) => {
  let defaultState = getDefaultState(serverProps)
  return (state = defaultState, action) => {

  }
}

let getStore = (serverProps) => {
  let reducer = getReducer(serverProps)
  return store = createStore(reducer)
}

let ConnectedApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

let ProvidedApp = (serverProps) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={getStore(serverProps)}>
      <ConnectedApp/>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

This is super ugly :/